Paragon backup. Еrror when converting files. Operation is not supported
I want to know, how to solve the problem and get access to files in backup. I prefer to mound backup as virtual drive and keep existing hard drive partitions. Backup restoration is not preferable. Sorry for non-ideal English.
Details
I have three installed Windows UEFI. There are 2 Windows 10 and 1 Windows 11. I reserved one windows 10 partition it with Paragon Hard disk manager, using incremental scheme of backup. Then I reduced partition size.  I made the following, trying to restore it. Created recovery media on flash drive. tried to restore. Then I browsed and found desirable backup. I got error, explaining there was other partitions structure.
I decided to convert pbf or pfi backup in virtual machine file, created recovery media based on Linux. I want to convert in one of the following formats: vmdk, pvhd, vhd, vhdx. It does not matter which. I plan to mount archive file as virtual drive. So, I restarted the device, selected option Export Vd in the  menu. See screenshots. Selected the backup file and incremental file date, entered password, choose desirable file extension for virtual machines. As a result there is message: "Operation is not supported".






I made some attempts: point first full backup as source file, changed file type of virtual machine (pvhd, vhd, vmdk. vhdx), declined boot sectors not to include them in the resulting file.  I received the same error.
Please answer 2 questions or write your opinion:

How to convert backups?
Should it be possible to restore from incremental backup, if the size of source partion will be increased?

Regards,
Alex.

Convert backups to what format exactly?

I want to convert in one of the following formats: vmdk, pvhd, vhd, vhdx. It does not matter which. I plan to mount archive file as virtual drive.

In that case what I would do is create a large enough VHDX, mount it within Windows, then restore the backup to the mounted volume. You will need more space than I can see in your screenshot for that VHDX.
